# Long data.frame() call works in interactive mode but occasionally fails in cronjob

Tags: r

I have an R Script that scrapes tweets using `streamR`. It's not 100% reproducible because you'll need your own oauth token from Twitter to run it. Every time I run the script in interactive mode it finishes successfully. However, I am running this in a cronjob every hour and I receive different sporadic error messages but it also sometimes finishes successfully. I've listed the error messages at the bottom. It appears that it's having a problem with the long `data.frame` call. Since the errors look scrambled and random, it almost seems like it's the same issue when you try to paste a lot of R code into a terminal at once and some characters get scrambled. I've tried using both `Rscript` and `R CMD BATCH` in my cronjob but the errors still persist.

```
library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)

## load oauth token
load("/home/ubuntu/Documents/Scripts/TwitterScrapes/mr_oauth.dat")

keywords <- "switch Sprint"
tweets <- filterStream( file="", track=keywords, oauth=my_oauth, timeout=3400)
tweets <- parseTweets(tweets)

tweets$text <- as.character(tweets$text)
tweets$text <- gsub("\n", "", tweets$text)
tweets$text <- gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", tweets$text)
tweets$description <- gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", tweets$description)
tweets$description <- gsub("\n", "", tweets$description)
tweets$name <- gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", tweets$name)
tweets$location <- gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", tweets$location)

tweets$att <- 0
tweets$sprint <- 0
tweets$verizon <- 0
tweets$tmobile <- 0
tweets$aio <- 0
tweets$cricket <- 0
tweets$gosmart <- 0
tweets$metropcs <- 0
tweets$virgin <- 0
tweets$boost <- 0
tweets$usc <- 0



cleaned <- data.frame(To = "", From = "", Phone.Availability = 0, Phone.Price = 0, Family.Plan = 0, Coverage.Availability = 0, Coverage.Quality = 0,
    Customer.Service =0,Data.Plan = 0, Upgrade.Plan = 0, Device.Promo = 0, Service.Promo = 0, Outage = 0, Plan.Price = 0, Wireline = 0,
    Wireline.Programming =0, Corportate = 0, Na = 0,Switch.Phrase = "", tweet = tweets$text, Date=tweets$created_at, Location = tweets$location,
    S.reviewed = 0, att = tweets$att, verizon = tweets$verizon,sprint = tweets$sprint, tmobile = tweets$tmobile, aio = tweets$aio,
    cricket = tweets$cricket, gosmart = tweets$gosmart, metro = tweets$metro,boost = tweets$boost, virgin = tweets$virgin, usc = tweets$usc,
    Idstr = tweets$id_str, Retweet = tweets$retweeted, Retweet_Count = tweets$retweet_count,In.reply.to.status.id = tweets$in_reply_to_status_id_str,
    In.reply.to.id = tweets$in_reply_to_user_id_str, Listed.count = tweets$listed_count,Verified = tweets$verified, Usr.id.str = tweets$user_id_str,
    Description = tweets$description, Geo.enabled = tweets$geo_enabled,Usr.created.at = tweets$user_created_at, Statuses.count = tweets$statuses_count,
    Followers.count = tweets$followers_count, Favorites = tweets$favourites_count,Name = tweets$name, Lang=tweets$lang, Utc.offset = tweets$utc_offset,
    Friends.count = tweets$friends_count, Screen.name = tweets$screen_name, Country.code = tweets$country_code, Country=tweets$country,
    Place.type = tweets$place_type, Full.name = tweets$full_name, Place.name = tweets$place_name, Place.id = tweets$place_id, source=tweets$source)
```

Examples of the errors:

```
Error in data.frame(To = "", From = "", Phone.Availability = 0, Phone.Price = 0,  : 
object 'tweetsd_str' not found
Execution halted

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "place_lat", value = c(NaN, NaN)) : 
replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
Calls: parseTweets -> $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Comment: Given that the code is running sometimes, its likely not a syntax error. I can't even find the tweetsd_str in your code above so most likely its somewhere within the streamR package. Can you start saving all the variables just before creating the last data.frame using save.image and see if you can manually run the last part using that data when there is an error.

Comment: I can spot that `tweetsd_str` is coming from `tweets$id_str`. If that helps... What I would do if I were you is try to rewrite a bit of the code so as to avoid that very long statement. It seems you could first put `tweets` in a data.frame, extract the columns you need, rename them with `colnames<-`, then `cbind` with the few extra fields  you have in the front.

Comment: It appears as if changing it to `R CMD BATCH` is working. I now only receive warnings, which I believe are related to the `sqldf` library. Error: "In value[[3L]](cond) : bind.data must have non-zero dimensions"